# Getting data on matplotllib in bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently working to try out matplotlib using object oriented interface. I'm still new to this tool.

This is the end result of the graph (using excel) I want to create using matplotlib.

[image]

I have load the table into dataframe which look like this.
[image]

Below is the code I wrote.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

loaddf = pd.read_excel("C:\\SampleRevenue.xlsx")

#to get the row on number of tickets
count = loaddf.iloc[0]
#to get the total proceeds I get from sellling the ticket
vol = loaddf.iloc[1]
#The profit from tickets after deducting costs
profit = loaddf.iloc[2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
ax.barh(str(count), list(loaddf.columns.values))
```

Somehow this is the graph I received. How do I display the number of tickers in bar form for each month? Intention is Y axis number of tickets and x axis on months
[image]

This is the count, vol and profit series after using iloc to extract the rows.
Do i need to remove the series before I use for plotting?
[image]

Comment: Just do `count.plot.barh()`?

Comment: Returns TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

Comment: Can you print(count) to see what it really contains?

Comment: Hi, these are the print results. ```print (count)
0     Ticket
1        100
2        200
3        300
4        440
5        561
6        600
7        760
8        800
9        999
10      1034
11      1100
12      1200
Name: 0, dtype: object```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that `read_excel` gets really confused when the dataframe is transposed. It expects the first row to be the titles of the columns, and each subsequent row a next entry. Optionally the first column contains the row labels. In that case, you have to add `index_col=0` to the parameters of `read_excel`. If you copy and paste-transpose everything while in Excel, it could work like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

loaddf = pd.read_excel("C:\\SampleRevenue_transposed\.xlsx", index_col=0)
loaddf[["Vol '000"]].plot(kind='bar', title ="Bar plot of Vol '000")
plt.show()
```

If you don't transpose the Excel, the header row gets part of the data, which causes the "no numeric data to plot" message.

Comment: Thanks. Quick question. I have edited the question with image of the count, vol and profit variables which hold the rows of information using iloc. Do i need to remove the index before using it for ploting? Thanks

Comment: No, if you remove the index, the bar plot won't know the labels for the bars. But you do need to remove the first row which is now "Ticket". The read_excel used it as simple text and didn't know to interpret it as column name.